# Link is broken when trying to access post

Tags: wordpress

I have a page where I query wpdb for posts related to a certain category. I also get the permalink each iteration with get_permalink() and create a link for each post. But when I click the link my browser tells me that the link is broken. This is the page that generates the post excerpts and permalinks etc:

```
        <div class="span9" id="content">

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">

            <?php $i = 1; foreach($programming_posts as $key => $post){

                var_dump(get_permalink($post->ID));

                /*Condition that creates a new row each two posts.*/

                if($i % 2 == 0){ ?>

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">

                        <?php } ?>

                            <div class="span6 well well-small" id="post-preview">

                            <div class="row-fluid">

                                <div class="span7"><b><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></b></div>

                                <div class="span5"><?php echo $post->post_date; ?></div>

                            </div>

                            <div><?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?></div>


                                <div class="pull-right">

                                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>"><b>Go to post</b></a>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                <?php if($i % 2 == 0){ ?>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- Closes the row-fluid div element. -->

                <?php $i++; } if($i > 8) break; } //Foreach loop end.?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

All of this is inside of "The Loop" and is working. Its just that the permalink that is generated is not working. I'm using this plugin to create templates and choose template for my posts: http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/

This is some arbitrary template php script I've created to see if it works and it is displaed properly under the scroll meny when you create a post and can choose template:

```
<?php

/*
Template Name Posts: ProgrammingTemplate
 */

get_header();
if(have_post()) while (have_posts()){ the_post();

?>

<?php var_dump(the_post());?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to custom post types, I've seen this issue be caused by permalinks not updating. First, I'd try going to the backend in Settings > Permalinks, and click "Save" twice (yes, twice). No need to change the structures or anything- just re-save.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Is var_dump() a mistake? I'd write the permalink into a variable.

```
$permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
echo $permalink;
```

Or of course if you wanted to wrap a link around it:

```
<a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>"><?php echo $permalink; ?></a>
```